# DJANGO: TemplateDoesNotExist: auth/user_confirm_delete.html

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I'm trying to create a "delete account" functionality in Django. I use `DeleteView` for this purpose.

The problem is that after calling this view, `Django` raises:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/delete-account/
Django Version: 1.11.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
auth/user_confirm_delete.html
```

My view:

```
class DeleteAccount(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = User

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        user = self.request.user
        userprofile = user.userprofile
        userprofile.prepare_to_delete_account()
        return user
```

Why it tries to render this `template` and why there is no such template if it's being called?

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The view renders a template to confirm that you want to delete the object.

By default it generates the template name `auth/user_confirm_delete.html` from the app and model name.

If you want to use another template, set `template_name`.

```
class DeleteAccount(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'delete_account.html'
```

You must create the template, Django does not include it. There is an example [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview) that you can extend:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

Comment: I understand. For this purpose, change GET to POST should be enough, thanks.

Comment: If you do that, you may still get server errors if users or bots access the URL directly with a GET request. You could set `http_method_names = ['POST']` to avoid this.